# How to move files with specific extensions to newly created directories

Tags: shell-script

I want to `mv` files with specific extensions to newly created directories. This script moves files with all the extentions in all the newly created folders, which is not the intent. Instead, it should move extension-specific files to specific folders. How can I accomplish that?

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
    mkdir -p backup/ch0${i}
    if [ $? -eq ]; then
        echo "directory backup/ch0${i} created"
        for j in c h sh
        do
            count=0
            count=`expr $count + 1`
            if [ $count==i ]; then
                cp /home/owner/*.${j} backup/ch0${i}
                if [ $count!=i ]; then
                    continue;
                elif [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                    break 2;
                fi
        done
    else
        echo "could not back up directory!!"
    fi 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
backup_extensions()
{
    count=0
    while [ -n "$1" ]
    do
        let count+=1
        mkdir -p backup/ch0${count}
        cp /home/owner/*.${1} backup/ch0${count} || return 2
        shift
    done
}

backup_extensions c h sh
```

Comment: Hi l0b0,  It worked..Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: what does return 2 mean here ?

Comment: Instead of answering 'It worked, thank's a lot!' you should vote l0b0 up (arrow up on the left) and probably select the check mark.

Comment: @CuriousCoder: `return 2` is used to signal an error and stop the processing. If a `cp` fails, you don't want to keep on trying with the other files, because it's likely to be a serious error (out of disk space or missing target directory).

Answer (score 1):

I have not verified this, but it should do the job.

```
backups=( 1:c 2:h 3:sh )

for set in "${backups[@]}"; do
 IFS=":" read dir_bkup file_ext <<< "$set"
 if ! mkdir -p "backup/ch0$dir_bkup"; then
  echo  "Could not create "backup/ch0$dir_bkup. Skipping"
  continue
 fi
 cp "/home/owner/"*".$file_ext" "backup/$dir_bkup/"
done
```