# How can you move (or copy) all files of a certain type to a directory in Unix?

Tags: grep, rename, file-copy

I'm not very familiar with all the tricks of `grep/find/awk/xargs` quite yet.

I have some files matching a particular pattern, say `*.xxx`. These files are in random places throughout a certain directory. How can I find all such files, and move them to a folder in my home directory on Unix (that may not exist yet)?

Comment: You've got to take care when talking about "file type". In unixy environments, the ".xxx" example isn't even an extension in the Windows sense.  ".xxx" just constitutes a suffix of the file name.  "File type" is more one of a few categories: regular file, device file, symbolic link, directory, named pipe, Unix-family socket, maybe a few others.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7027/how-to-move-files-with-specific-extensions-to-newly-created-directories

Comment: @BruceEdiger thanks I guess I really meant "filename pattern"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
mkdir ~/dst
find source -name "*.xxx" -exec mv -i {} -t ~/dst \;
```

Comment: I would use `mv -i -t ~/dst {} +`

Answer (score 18):

If you want to move all the files inside a directory hierarchy to a single destination directory, in bash ≥4 (put `shopt -s globstar` in your `~/.bashrc`) or zsh:

```
mkdir ~/new-directory
mv -i **/*.xxx ~/new-directory
```

In other shells:

```
mkdir ~/new-directory
find . -name '*.xxx' -exec mv -i {} ~/new-directory \;
```

How to read this `find` command:

- `.`: traverse the current directory
- `-name '*.xxx'`: act on files whose name matches this pattern
- `-exec … \;`: perform this command on each file, replacing `{}` by the path to the file

There's a more complex command using `find` that's faster if you have many files as it doesn't need to invoke a separate `mv` process for each file:

```
find . -name '*.xxx' -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$@" "$0"' ~/new-directory {} +
```

The `+` at the end tells `find` to invoke the command on multiple files at a time. Since `find` can only put the file names at the end of the command line, and `mv` needs to have the destination directory last, we use an intermediate shell to rearrange the arguments (`"$0"` is the first argument to the shell, `~/new-directory`, and `"$@"` are the subsequent arguments coming from `find`'s expansion of `{}`).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to replicate the directory structure of the matching source files to the new target directory, you can make use of GNU cp's *--parents* option:

```
mkdir /path/to/target_dir
cd source_dir
find . -name '*.xxx' -exec cp -iv --parents -t /path/to/target_dir {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use find without ‍‍`-exec‍` as well:

```
mkdir /path/to/dest    
cp `find /path/to/source -name "*.jar"` /path/to/dest
```

Comment: Note however that `find -exec` is much safer; the above will fail on file names containing white space, for example.