# copy mp3 to a target directory maintaining directory structure and deleting files when copy complete

Tags: linux, bash

Found this answer here for copying files and keeping directory structure.

[copy files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30734/11267)

```
find . -name '*.xxx' -exec cp -iv --parents -t /path/to/target_dir {} +
```

Is there an easy way to maintain the list of copied files and delete the files from the source directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Delete the files from the source directory" usually translates to `mv`. Unfortunately `mv` does not have an option like `--parent`. The easiest solution with `cp` is probably: Call `cp` once for every file. Inefficient but easy to code:

```
find . -type f \
  -name '*.xxx' -exec cp -iv --parents {} /path/to/target_dir \; -delete
```

The file is deleted if `cp` exits successfully. `-delete` may be specific to GNU `find`.

Comment: @Huake Laging   So this will traverse into sub directories?

Comment: @sayth Does your `find` code?

Comment: find . -name '*.xxx' -exec cp -iv --parents {} /path/to/target_dir \; -delete had to remove the -type f, it worked perfect then.

Comment: @sayth That is very strange as `-type f` means "act on regular files only" (excluding directories, FIFOs, device files and the like).

Comment: sayth:~$ find . -type f \ -name '*.mp3' -exec cp -iv --parents {} /home/sayth/Music \; -delete
find: paths must precede expression:  -name
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: @sayth Do you have a newline after the `\ ` (as in my answer) of have you put all that in one line? If it is one line only then you have to remove the `\ `.

Comment: All on one line